# Microsoft Identity causes a crash in an Azure Web App

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity, azure-webapps

I am trying my first steps with Azure. I have uploaded a webapp (Blazor Wasm server hosts), but using the RoleManger or UserManager causes a crash. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to enable logs in an Azure web app (that's another question here on the forum).
I could find out through many attempts that even simple queries do not work. However, I have no problems with my local database.
No matter which of the lines is executed, the app crashes. Therefore I assume that it has something to do with the configuration.

```
var adminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("adminRoleName");
var superUserInDb = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin");
```

Edit:
I tried a Web-Api Call to get the errormessage. I get a error "Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.". that is right, i change with the modelbuider the name and schema from the table.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity =>
            {
entity.ToTable(name: "Users", "Identity")
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely nothing we can do without knowing more. What do you mean by "crash"? Do you have an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: When the app starts, i get a website with message ":( Application Error" and a option to look to the diagnostic resources. It said, there are 8x 503 Server Unavailable-Error. But i think, this is a wrong message. i don't have more information. I cant get the Logs.

Comment: I tried a api call and i get a error message "Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'." edit above.

Comment: "Invalid object name" probably means you are pointing at the wrong or empty database.

Comment: That is right, but i have rename it. see my code above. I don't understand, why the usermanger use the old name. the database is currently created.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i have many changes with the modelbuilder from dbcontext. I used `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` twice. First on start the buildings and somewhere behind the identity-changes.